# How Would I Make an If Statement From Arguments in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

I need to pass certain parameters into a function and have that function pull from an array based on the arguments passed to it.  It's hard to explain, so I'll show you what I'm trying to do.

```
function SearchDeck(deck,...){
    var tryagain = true;
    do{
        if(deck[0].property == value){
            //do something;
            tryagain = false;
        }
        else{
            deck.splice(0,1);
        }
    }
    while(tryagain);
}
```

There are multiple decks to look in, the proper deck will be passed in.  I want to always be drawing off the top of the deck (index 0 of the array).  I need to draw continuously until I find a card that matches what I'm after. I splice out the 0 index if it doesn't match.  What I'm after is dynamic, varying across the properties or even the operators I would use.
Some examples of if statements I would have are...

```
deck[0].color == "orange"
deck[0].value >= 5
deck[0].value < -4
```

I could make multiple functions or have the function fork based on an argument, but that doesn't seem like the best way to go about this.

Comment: Just as a note -- As a more Object-Oriented approach you could make a `deck` object and add the `search` method to it.  Then you could say `deck.search(callbackFunction);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding this correctly, you want the behavior of the `if(deck[0].property == value)` to be different for each invocation of the `SearchDeck(...)` function?

My recommendation would be to pass in a function:

```
function SearchDeck(deck, validationFunction, ...){
    var tryagain = true;
    do{
        if(validationFunction(deck[0])){
            //do something;
            tryagain = false;
        }
        else{
            deck.splice(0,1);
        }
    }
    while(tryagain);
}
```

Then when you call the code, you can do:

```
SearchDeck(deck, function(firstCard) { return firstCard.color == "orange" }, ...);
SearchDeck(deck, function(firstCard) { return firstCard.value >= 5 }, ...);
SearchDeck(deck, function(firstCard) { return firstCard.value < -4 }, ...);
```

Or, if the cases you're looking for might be reused, it might also be cleaner to make those named functions:

```
function validateColor(firstCard) {
  return firstCard.color == "orange";
}

function validateHighValue(firstCard) {
  return firstCard.value >= 5;
}

function validateLowValue(firstCard) {
  return firstCard.value < -4;
}

SearchDeck(deck, validateColor, ...);
SearchDeck(deck, validateHighValue, ...);
SearchDeck(deck, validateLowValue, ...);
```

Comment: Ah, a callback is probably a better solution than mine.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be interested in the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) operator:

```
if (typeof deck == 'object') { ... }
if (typeof deck[0].color == 'string') { ... }
if (typeof deck[0].value == 'number') { ... }
```

Alternatively:

```
if (deck[0].hasOwnProperty('color')) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with. You need to push the way of check (either "== 'oragne'" or "<3") as string.

```
function searchDeck() {

    var deck = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
        tryagain = true,
        string = deck[deck.length - 1];

    deck.pop();

    while (tryagain) {

        if (eval('deck[0].property' + string)) {
            //do something;
            alert('card found');
            tryagain = false;
        } else {
            deck.splice(0, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is what you wanted ;)

[Here is a working jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/xty5fwwr/), of course there might be a more elegant way, this is just what I came up with. Note that eval can be dangerous, so you should be carefull if user picks what the test will be (the string pushed into the array).